# Alternative methods for providing a config file to an OpenTelemetry container in ECS/Fargate without using the --config command

Tags: open-telemetry

I'm planning to run an OpenTelemetry container in ECS/Fargate and I'm seeking a simpler approach for providing a config file to the container. I'd prefer not to create a separate volume solely for storing this config file. Are there any alternative methods for supplying a config file to an OpenTelemetry container other than using the --config command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AWS parameter store to store entire config file

Answer (score 3):

The collector includes a [number of configuration providers](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/confmap/provider) that can be used with `--config` in addition to the file-based provider.  If you're using the contrib or ADOT distributions there is also an [S3 provider](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/confmap/provider/s3provider) that can be used to load configuration from S3.  ECS task definition can be used to load configuration from other sources into an environment variable and then use `env://<VAR_NAME>` to have the collector load configuration from that environment variable.